# Operate on a list of numbers using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of numbers as below. How can I select the numbers and multiply them by 2 using LINQ?

```
var Mylist = new List<int> {1,2,3,4};

---> MyNewList = {2,4,6,8}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select` to project values:

```
var MyNewList = MyList.Select(x => x * 2).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, if I want to add a condition to this, for example if I only want to select odd numbers should I use `Where` before `Select`?

Comment: @Vahid yes, `.Where(n => n % 2 == 1).Select...`

Answer (score 2):

```
Mylist.Select(i => i * 2);
```

This returns a new IEnumerable with the selector function returning the passed value multiplied by 2.

Answer (score 2):

`var list = new List<int> {1,2,3,4};
var doubledList = list.Select(x=> x*2).ToList();`